# Repository and Service Tier Interaction Question

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, service, repository-pattern

I have a generic repository interface, that has the usual methods for saving, reading and querying from the service tier like so:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
    void Save(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

If I have a service, for example a User service that uses a concrete implementation of the `IRepository` with `User` as its type (`IRepository<User>`), if the service itself might need something from another `IRepository` say `IRepository<Admin>` should the service call `IRepository<Admin>` directly, or should it call an associated service (i.e., the service that primarily deals with the `IRepository<Admin>` repository)?

I personally can see an issue if you are pulling items directly from a repository, if say you wanted to apply certain business rules before the results are returned to a client, but on the other-hand a service might want to work on the raw result set and to apply its own rules to the results, so I am a bit confused about which direction to take, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation detail of all the repositories is same, you could probably create an abstract BaseRepository, for example:

```
protected abstract class BaseRepo<T> : IRepository<T>
     where T : class
{
    #region IRepository Members

    // Implement all IRepository members here and make them public

    #endregion
}
```

then you can create a dedicated AdminRepository, for example:

```
public class AdminRepo : BaseRepo<Admin> {}
```

and to call from another repository you can do the following:

```
public class UserRepo : BaseRepo<User>
{
    private AdminRepo adminRepo = new AdminRepo();

    public UserRepo()
    {
        Admin person = adminRepo.GetById(1);
    }
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Raghu, my question isn't really how to implement a repository but rather whether or not it is okay for a given service to call more than one repository.

Comment: Absolutely IMHO. It is a common scenario for a service to have dependencies on multiple repos/facades. However if you are worried about creating concrete instances within your service, you can use an IoC conatiner to inject repository dependencies at runtime. Having one service providing contextually related data to your client will simplify your design as well.

Comment: cheers, we use structure map as our IoC container for any dependencies.